# Split unequally occurring comma-separated strings to columns and fill with missing values

Tags: r, string, split, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with comma-separated strings:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a,b,c", "a", "a,b"))
```

I'd like to split the strings into separate columns, resulting in 3 new columns. For the rows with fewer than 3 strings, columns should be filled with missing values.

What I have tried so far is to use the `strsplit` command:

```
dfb <- strsplit(df, ",")
```

Returns an error:

> non-character argument

I have also tried separate, and this would provide the additional "fill right" feature:

```
dfnew2 <- separate(df, c("X","Y"), sep = ",", fill = "right")
```

This Returns Error:

> `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a
>   character vector

My expected result should be a data frame like:

```
X Y   Z
a b   c
a n/a n/a
a b   n/a
```

Do you have any suggestions? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `read.table`:

```
read.table(text = as.character(df$x), sep = ",", as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE,
  na.strings = "")
```

giving:

```
  V1   V2   V3
1  a    b    c
2  a <NA> <NA>
3  a    b <NA>
```

Comment: A beautiful solution! Just out of curiosity, is there an elegant way to deal with situations in which the elements in strings are not ordered (like `c("a,b,c", "a", "b,a")`)? Meaning, to have the same letters in the same columns.

Comment: Convert it to dcf form and then use `read.dcf`. like this: `read.dcf(textConnection(gsub("([^,]*)(,|$)", "\\1:\\1\n", df$x)))`

Comment: Brilliant, this solution did work for me. Don't forget to specify the column ($x)! Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 mutate(x = strsplit(x, ",", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 spread(x, x) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  a    b    c
1 a    b    c
2 a <NA> <NA>
3 a    b <NA>
```

With more compact column names:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 mutate(x = strsplit(x, ",", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 spread(x, x) %>%
 rename_at(2:length(.), ~ paste("var", 1:length(.), sep = "_")) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  var_1 var_2 var_3
1     a     b     c
2     a  <NA>  <NA>
3     a     b  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "x")
#   x_1  x_2  x_3
#1:   a    b    c
#2:   a <NA> <NA>
#3:   a    b <NA>
```

---

Use `cSplit_e` if your input data is slightly more complex

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a,b,c", "a", "a,b", "d,b"))
cSplit_e(df, "x", type = "character", mode = "value", drop = TRUE)
#   x_a  x_b  x_c  x_d
#1    a    b    c <NA>
#2    a <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3    a    b <NA> <NA>
#4 <NA>    b <NA>    d
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not yet have comment privileges, so I will provide some additional insight to the nice answer provided by G. Grothendieck here.

Sometimes there will be leading and trailing spaces when splitting unequally occurring comma-separated strings, which will create problems if you are using any of them as key variables for merging or trying to use conditional statements based on the values of the new string variables.

I would suggest using the `str_strim()` in the `stringr` package to deal with this issue.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(x = c("a,b,c", "a", "a,b"))
read.table(text = as.character(df$x), sep = ",", as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE,
  na.strings = "") %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = where(is.character), .fns = ~ str_trim(.x, side = "both")))
```

You can also use `trimws()` included in base R (version 3.2.0 and above) to remove the leading and trailing spaces. But `stringr::str_trim()` can remove some mutant whitespaces that `trimws()` is unable to remove at times.

Hope this helps.